# Why I can't use "laravel" command inside Homestead VM

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, composer-php, homestead

I am new to laravel.

So, I have successfully installed and configured Homestead on my Windows machine.

Then I wanted to install Laravel. As I said, I am on Windows, so obviously I don't want to install php, composer and all that stuff on it, that's why I just hit **"vagrant ssh"** to get inside Homestead and then tried to install laravel following the official documention

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Then I tried to run "laravel" command, but no luck - command not found. I decided, that I had to edit PATH variable, but then I found out that there is no "`~/.composer/vendor/bin`" folder at all (not it inside /home/vagrant or /root).
and after I got stuck. What do I do wrong, guys?

P.S. "`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`" works fine, but I want to find out how to make "laravel" command work

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a `laravel` command-line executable.

Are you trying to run `artisan` commands?

[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan)

Comment: [Installation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/installation#installation):
_Make sure to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory (or the equivalent directory for your OS) in your PATH so the laravel executable can be located by your system._

Comment: And then:
laravel new blog

Answer (score 0):

when you run `composer global require "laravel/installer"` what did it say ? it should output

```
Changed current directory to /home/vagrant/.config/composer where laravel will be installed
```

so you can just add `/home/vagrant/config/composer/vendor/bin` (note `config` vs what you say `~/.composer/vendor/bin`) in your `PATH` variable and `laravel` command will work